# La diferencia entre "He" y "Hay"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

What is the difference between *He* and *Hay*?  I always hear the phrase *Hay mucha información* but I just saw the phrase *He aquí algunos gráficos....*

---

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre *he* y *hay*? Por ejemplo, siempre oigo la frase *Hay mucha información* y acabo de ver la frase *He aquí algunos gráficos...*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La primera respuesta a tu pregunta sería que las dos son formas del [**presente de indicativo del verbo haber**](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ESverbs.aspx?v=haber). **`He`** corresponde a la **1ª persona del singular**, y **`hay`** corresponde a la forma **impersonal de la 3ª persona de singular**.

Tu pregunta estaría quizás mejor formulada si preguntases por la diferencia entre **`he aquí`** y **`hay`**. La [R.A.E.](http://dle.rae.es/he) viene a decir básicamente esto:

> **He aquí**
>          *Se usa para señalar o mostrar a alguien o algo.*
>
> **Hay**
>  
>          *Estar realmente en alguna parte. Hallarse o existir real o figuradamente.*

Yo creo que la diferencia en tus frases está en que:

- Cuando dices **`hay mucha información`** quieres decir que existe cierta información, pero esa información puede estar en unas bases de datos en internet, en unos libros de la biblioteca municipal o en los gráficos que tienes delante.
- En cambio, cuando dices **`he aquí unos gráficos`** también quieres decir que existen ciertos gráficos, pero implica que vas a mostrar unos gráficos en este momento y que los tienes delante, ya sea en el siguiente párrafo de un artículo que estás escribiendo o en la pantalla del ordenador si estás realizando una presentación.

Comment: Para mí el `he` de `he aquí` no tiene sentido como presente indicativo en primera persona.  Por ahora no tengo otras construcciones análogas con `haber`, pero en construcciones análogas con `aquí` podemos ver: `Sea aquí un ítem`, `Vaya aquí un dato`, etc. parecieran construcciones con tercera persona del subjuntivo/imperativo.  ¿Podría ser una especie de imperativo impersonal?

Comment: Creo que "he" en ese contexto no es una conjugación del verbo haber. Al menos, [aparece como una entrada propia en el diccionario](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=Vdqi7BIHdDXX2DkNVIMt|mOOAsiZWEDXX2LnvVQBK)

Comment: Me parece que el sentido original de _he aquí_ es _aquí tengo_ o _aquí (os/les) presento_, ya que el verbo _haber_, en una de sus acepciones (poco usada en español moderno) es sinónimo de _tener_.

Comment: @MikMik y otros. Yo creo lo mismo. Por eso pongo que la primera respuesta a la pregunta tal y como esta formulada seria esa, pero en el siguiente parrafo explico que la pregunta deberia estar formulada de otro modo para que haga referencia a lo que realmente creo que se quiere preguntar. No es lo mismo preguntar por la diferencia entre he y hay, que preguntar por la diferencia entre he aqui y hay! Ademas, en mi respuesta hay un enlace a ese mismo articulo que mencionas... P.S. lo siento por las tildes pero estoy en un teclado ingles...

Comment: La etimología que presenta @MikMik (adverbio proveniente del árabe _há_, _hā_) haría de la construcción _“He aquí unos gráficos”_ una construcción gramaticalmente coja (adv.+adv.+art.+subs.), pero en mi opinión es una frase completa.  Podría funcionar si no fuera una frase predicativa sino una interjección.  La sugerencia de deStrangis como conjugación de _haber_ (del lat. _habēre_) con el significado de _tener_ sí sugiere una conjugación en primera persona, y da origen a una frase predicativa completa.

Answer (score 5):

"[haber](http://dle.rae.es/haber)" is a very special and tricky word: it's main usage -first meaning- is as an auxiliar word to form compound verbs tenses, like "have" in English; but we are not concerned with that usage in this case.

No difficulties with "**hay**" : it's the present indicative tense of "**haber**", but in the impersonal form (see entry 8 ), meaning just "**there is**" (or "**there are**").

"**he**": normally this word is the present form of "haber" in the first meaning: "yo he dormido bien = I have slept well". But **"he aquí"** is a very special *ad hoc* construct which has its [own entry](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=Vdqi7BIHdDXX2DkNVIMt%7CmOOAsiZWEDXX2LnvVQBK) in the dictionary, and which cannot be descomposed or converted to other tenses or persons. It's an slightly stilized and emphatic way of manifesting the immediante existence or ocurrence of something to someone, like, say: "see here, there is..."

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use "He" for making emphasis on something (the thing you're referring to) or for highlighting a conclusion. It's not very common to use it on a daily basis, because it's generally used in contexts such as talks or speeches.

"Hay" on the other hand it's more used in informal conversations.

In your example "*Hay mucha información*" refers to having lots of information in a more general context, but "*He aquí algunos gráficos*" means that you're exposing some topic and pointing to the graphs as a way of enforcing your argument.

---

Usualmente se usa "He" para hacer énfasis en algo (la cosa a la que te refieres) o para resaltar una conclusión. No es muy común usarlo a diario porque generalmente se utiliza en contextos tales como charlas o discursos.

"Hay", por otro lado, es más usado en conversaciones informales.

En tu ejemplo "*Hay mucha información*" se refiere a tenere mucha información en un contexto más general, pero "*He aquí algunos gráficos*" significa que estás exponiendo algún tema e indicando los gráficos como una forma de reforzar tu argumento.

Answer (score -1):

`he` is used in the sense of `here is`.

`hay` is used in the sense of `there is`.